# Determine whether a given set can be partitioned into two subsets such that the sum of elements in both subsets is same

Tags: algorithm, partitioning

The solutions already on internet use DP or recursion to solve the question. But arent the following two conditions enough to determine it:-

1: The sum of the elements must be even.

2: The biggest element has to be less or equal than the sum of all the other elements.

Comment: Notice the next counter example: `[3,5,6]`

Comment: The 2 conditions you present are necessary conditions, but they are not sufficient. It means that any set which does not respect one of the two conditions cannot be partitioned in two equal sum subsets. But as shows the counter example provided, these are not sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the next counter example: `[3,5,6]`

It does match the conditions:

1. Sum is 14
2. The biggest element is 6 < 3 + 5